# Android SDK - Using Gesture API, would like gesture to stay on screen after being recognized

Tags: android, gesture-recognition

I'm using the Gesture API with a Gesture Library that I created, and it is working really well.  The problem is that I would like the gesture to be visible on the screen after OnGesturePerformedListener exits, but instead the gesture is erased.  I was thinking that perhaps there is an event after OnGesturePerformedListener -- I could save the gesture in OnGesturePerformedListener and then display it again in this later event.  Anyone know if there is such an event?  Here is the code:

```
   private OnGesturePerformedListener handleGestureListener = new OnGesturePerformedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView gestureView,
                                       Gesture gesture) {
            if (gesture.getStrokesCount() != 2){
                setWonderEmoticon();
                return;
            }
            ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = gLib.recognize(gesture);
            // one prediction needed
            if (predictions.size() > 0) {
                Prediction prediction = predictions.get(0);
                // checking prediction
                if (prediction.score > 20.0) {
                    setHappyEmoticon();
                }
                else {
                    setWonderEmoticon();
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

By the way, the same thing happens when setWonderEmoticon() and setHappyEmoticon() are removed from the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that works fine with the `OnGesturePerformedListener`:

**MainActivity.java**:

```
// ...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GestureOverlayView.OnGesturePerformedListener, GestureOverlayView.OnGestureListener {

    GestureOverlayView mGestureView;
    ImageView mImageView;
    TextView mText;
    Paint mPaint;
    Bitmap mBitmap;
    Canvas mCanvas;
    GestureLibrary mGestureLib;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        mGestureView = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gesture_overlay);
        mGestureView.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
        mGestureView.addOnGestureListener(this);

        mGestureView.setGestureColor(Color.BLACK);
        mGestureView.setUncertainGestureColor(Color.BLACK);
        mGestureView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                mGestureView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mGestureView.getWidth(), mGestureView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
            }
        });

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12.0f);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.GRAY);

        mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        mGestureLib = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.gesture);
        mGestureLib.load();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView gestureOverlayView, Gesture gesture) {
        if (gesture.getStrokesCount() > 0) {
            ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = mGestureLib.recognize(gesture);
            for (GestureStroke stroke : gesture.getStrokes()) {
                Path path = stroke.getPath();
                mCanvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
            }
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
            if (!predictions.isEmpty()) {
                Prediction best = predictions.get(0);
                mText.setText(String.format("Gesture: %s", best.name));
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

**activity_main.xml** ([snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqnbhm.png)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="onl.nok.gestures.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Waiting ..."
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/image_view" />

    <android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
        android:id="@+id/gesture_overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gestureStrokeType="single"
        android:fadeEnabled="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**How to apply new gestures?**

1. Track gestures with the Android app [Gesture Builder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pack.GestureApp)
2. Create a resource folder `raw` in your project:
   `<Project>/app/src/main/res/raw/`
3. Copy the generated file `gesture.txt` from your device:
   `/Android/data/pack.GestureApp/files/gesture.txt`
4. And finally paste it to the created folder `raw`:
   `<Project>/app/src/main/res/raw/gesture.txt`

Finally I pushed the source code to GitHub: https://github.com/nok/android-gesture-libraries

---

**2nd edit**:

You're right. So I use a simple `ImageView` to draw the performed gestures. Furthermore you can change the style in `mPaint` of type [Paint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html). You can find all changes in the pushed commit [82eabfb](https://github.com/nok/android-gesture-libraries/commit/82eabfbd408d3157be7b853ed6a9ec6f9bf2daa2) and [5ce427d](https://github.com/nok/android-gesture-libraries/commit/5ce427d5a1cb1c8e2bc64c681691c882037ca776) on GitHub.

Comment: This works exactly the way my code does -- no value added.  The gesture disappears from the screen but I want it to remain on the screen

Comment: I'm hoping there is another event that occurs when the gesture is performed but before it disappears.

Comment: Okay, I edited my answer, maybe the changes can answer your question.

Comment: Using these attributes, the gesture stays on the screen longer, but this just delays the start of onGesturePerformed.  I need it to stay on the screen when onGesturePerformed ends.

Comment: You're right. Sorry, I didn't notice that. In the last edit I use a simple canvas to draw the performed gestures. Check it out.